# Qual relacionamento entre o MVC e os Padrões de Projetos?

Tags: mvc, design-pattern

Sabemos que o Padrão MVC (Model View Controller) não é um Design Pattern, mas sim padrão de arquitetura. Ele também não é um padrão em camadas, pois este diz como agrupar componentes enquanto o MVC diz como os componentes interagem.

O MVC utiliza alguns padrões.
Quais Padrões de Projetos usa o MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No livro **Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software**, considerado a bíblia dos Desing Patterns, é citado o padrão MVC na linguagem Smalltalk. 
Segundo o livro, o padrão MVC usa os seguintes design patterns:

#### Observer

Usado no desacoplamento de View das Models de forma que mudanças na Model reflitam em todas as Views.

#### Composite

Usado para utilização de Views aninhadas e criação de componentes complexos como controles.

#### Strategy

Usado na relação View - Controller. Ao mudar a instância de controller que a view responde, você muda a estratégia de manipulação da View.

---

O livro ainda cita os seguintes design patterns que podem ser usados no MVC, mas são um pouco específicos a implementação Smalltalk ao qual o livro se refere.

**Factory Method** - Pode ser usado para definir a instância padrão de um Controller para uma View.

**Decorator** - Para adicionar rolagem a uma View

Pode [ler aqui](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=6oHuKQe3TjQC&lpg=PT33&pg=PT37#v=onepage&q&f=false) o trecho que fala especificamente disso.

Porém cada implementação específica do MVC vai utilizar um ou outro Design Pattern a mais ou a menos. O **ASP.NET MVC** por exemplo, utiliza algo bem próximo do pattern **Command** quando se utiliza o `ActionResult` no retorno. Diferentes retornos como `JsonResult`, `ViewResult` ou `PartiaViewResult` reprentam comandos diferentes que serão executados pelo framework no retorno do controle.